# Reading a google doc without user login

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to create a simple webpage that loads text from a google doc I have. The page will only ever read from the doc and will run client side, no server as the page is hosted on github. No need for users to login.

For example a section of text in the Google doc will hold descriptions for projects I have made. The web page will pull this text into a string and display it to the client.

I have set up a google cloud project, enabled the google doc api, and set up an api key. I have tried digging through Google's documentation but am getting lost in the swath of information geared towards bigger projects that are seemingly meant to access and modify different google account's docs. I've also tried finding similar solutions here but they all deal with google sheets and I cant even identify what might be calls to google or how to even start on the code side of this.

I am also extremely new to using Google api so this is all becoming overwhelming for what I thought would be a simple action. I Thought I could just pass the key and doc id into some api call and get the doc.

How do I use Javascript and or Node.js to let my page simply grab the data from a doc?

**Update**
Here is the function I now have

```
async function printGoogleDoc(docID, apiKey){
await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${docID}/export?mimeType=text/plain&key=${apiKey}`)
.then(function(res) {
    return res.text();
}).then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
}).catch(function() {
    console.log("error");
});
}
```

This uses the Drive API rather than the Doc API, which is what I thought I needed to use, and prints the contents of the doc. Now with more experimenting I will be able to store the contents and use them how I wish.

Comment: API keys only work with public data you will need to set the file to public.

Comment: Ok. If the doc is public what would the code look like to get the doc? Would I still need to do some kind of authentication or does an api key handle that? I don't have much knowledge on how interactions like this on the web work so I don't know what is necessary.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand your expected values from your Google Document. So, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? Because I thought that the method for approaching your goal might depend on your expected value. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike I added an example but all I'm truly trying to accomplish is getting text from a google doc stored as a string.

Comment: @Tanaike Do not worry. I appreciate that you tried to help. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer by guessing your goal. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just my guess. I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve a Google Document as text data.
- Your Google Document has already been publicly shared.
- You want to achieve this using an API key.

In this case, how about the following method?

#### Pattern 1

In this pattern, ["Method: files.export" of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/export) is used. Please replace `{documentId}` and `{your API key}` with the Google Document ID of your Google Document and your API key, respectively. In this case, Drive API is required to be enabled at the API console. And, please request the following URL with the GET method. By this, the Google Document is exported as text data.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{documentId}/export?mimeType=text%2Fplain&key={your API key}
```

#### Pattern 2

In this pattern, `exportLinks` of ["Method: files.get" of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get) is used. Please replace `{documentId}` with the Google Document ID of your Google Document. In this case, when the Document is publicly shared, the API key is not required to be used. And, please request the following URL with the GET method. By this, the Google Document is exported as text data.

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?exportFormat=txt&id={documentId}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked well. I guess I needed to use the Drive api rather than the Doc api. I did need to make one adjustment though for the mimeType in the https you sent. You use "mimeType=text%2Fplain", I had to make it "mimeType=text/plain" to work. Following that used .then(function(res) { return res.text(); }) to retrieve the text. This was a big help and I have much to learn

Comment: @Panthera Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could understand your question with your cooperation. Thank you, too.